# Woocommerce dependent attributes

Tags: customization

I'd like to add a product attribute which is dependent on another product attribute.  For example:

Material: Wood | Plastic | Leather

Color: <different values for wood, plastic, and leather>

This functionality doesn't seem to be built in.  How should I approach coding this?

Comment: If you just created variations with valid material and colour combinations then the material and colour options would narrow down based on the current selection automatically.

Comment: Yes but the number of combinations is extremely large.  I was thinking that perhaps I could create a filter to return the relevant subset for each material type.

Comment: So you're asking for how to filter this when creating the products? Or when users are purchasing them? Are you using variable products or something else? If it's for when users are purchasing them, and for variable products, then does that mean you've already created variations you don't want people to purchase?

Comment: I have just created the default variations (all materials, all colors).  I want the correct 
 (appropriate) colors to show when users are purchasing them, based on the material they have selected.